# Play a sequence of MP3 in Javascript on chrome

Tags: javascript, html

The code bellow loads some audio resources and according to the array `sNumbers` it plays the files. Each file has the `onended` event to play the next and so on.
The problem is when it loads the HTML page for the first time, those audios doesn't play at all. It throws the message `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException`
The second time, when I press F5 on the chrome it works properly.

I tryed `autoplay` hoping the audio play only after it be loaded.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <head>
    <title>SENHA</title>

    <script src="js1/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

    <audio src="voz/notify.wav" id="somN" preload="auto"></audio>
    <audio src="voz/senha.mp3" id="somS" preload="auto"></audio>
    <audio src="voz/0.mp3" id="som0" preload="auto"></audio>
    <audio src="voz/1.mp3" id="som1" preload="auto"></audio>
    <audio src="voz/2.mp3" id="som2" preload="auto"></audio>
    <audio src="voz/3.mp3" id="som3" preload="auto"></audio>
    <audio src="voz/4.mp3" id="som4" preload="auto"></audio>
    <audio src="voz/5.mp3" id="som5" preload="auto"></audio>
    <audio src="voz/6.mp3" id="som6" preload="auto"></audio>
    <audio src="voz/7.mp3" id="som7" preload="auto"></audio>
    <audio src="voz/8.mp3" id="som8" preload="auto"></audio>
    <audio src="voz/9.mp3" id="som9" preload="auto"></audio>
    <audio src="voz/consultorio.mp3" id="somC" preload="auto"></audio>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function (){
        let sNumbers = ['N', 'S', '1', '3'];
            let audios = [];
            sNumbers.map(function(e, i){
                audios.push( document.getElementById("som"+sNumbers[i]) );
            });
            audios.map(function(e,i){
                console.log(e);
                if (audios.length-1 != i){
                    audios[i].onended = function(){                
                        audios[i+1].play();
                    }
                }
            });
            audios[0].autoplay = true;
        }
    );

    </script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Chrome will not autoplay audio on page load; it requires user interaction like a button click, etc.

Comment: No, it plays automatically on the second load, when I press F5 on the browser.

Comment: You've interacted with the page at that point -- by pressing F5.

Comment: I tryed using the method play() (audios[0].play();) insted of the property autoplay. No success

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes